# implication behind "can I ask you to ..."

Tags: meaning-in-context, idiom-meaning

Is there any difference between these two sentences ?
    (1) Can I ask you to ...[do something]?
    (2) Can you ... [do something]?

Eg., if my boss were to say to me "Can I ask you to pick up the client?". Would that mean the same thing as "Can you pick up the client?"

Thanks

Comment: Both versions mean "I want you to pick up the client."

Answer (score 1):

Practically the two forms are the same. Technically, however, the questions are different. When you boss asks you "Can I ask you to ...", he is technically asking if he can make the request, not making the request.

[Note: I would not advise an employee to make an issue of the difference between "Can I ask you..." and "Can you...". If the boss asks you if you can do something, I'd personally be likely to ignore the "... I ask ..." bit.

Answer (score 1):

The effect of the two requests is more or less the same, but I would sense a slight difference in emphasis.

(2) is a straightforward request, slightly more polite than a direct order, to do something that would probably be considered quite normal within the terms of the job.

(1) is more tentative - it might be used when taking the request slightly outside the normal duties for the job, as a special favour, without sounding over-demanding.